# Add column to dataframe that shows frequency of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, count, frequency

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
  location   species
1  seattle   A
2  buffalo   C
3  seattle   D
4  newark    J
5  boston    Q
```

I would like to append a column to this frame that shows the number of times a location appears in the data set, with a result like this:

```
  location   species    freq-loc
1  seattle   A          2           #there are 2 entries with location=seattle
2  buffalo   C          1           #there is 1 entry with location=buffalo
3  seattle   D          2
4  newark    J          1
5  boston    Q          1
```

I know using `table(data$location)` can give me a contingency table. But I don't know how to map each value in the table to a corresponding entry in the dataframe. Can somebody help?

---

**Update**

Thank you so much for all the help! Just for interest, I ran a benchmark test to see how the merge, plyr and ave solutions ran compared to each other. The testing set is a 10,000 rows subset of my original 10 by ~7mil data set.:

```
Unit: milliseconds
expr         min         lq     median        uq       max neval
MERGE 110.877337 111.989406 112.585420 113.51679 120.23588   100
PLYR   26.305645  27.080403  27.576580  27.87157  68.40763   100
AVE     2.994528   3.117255   3.179898   3.35834  10.02955   100
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a base R way with `ave`.

```
transform(d, freq.loc = ave(seq(nrow(d)), location, FUN=length))
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure someone will post an (ugly;)) `ave` or `plyr` solution shortly, but here's the `data.table` one:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(your_df)

dt[, `freq-loc` := .N, by = location]
# note: using `-quotes around your var name, because of the "-" in the name
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base: *table* then *merge*:

```
merge(data, data.frame(table(location = data$location)), by = "location")
# location species Freq
# 1   boston       Q    1
# 2  buffalo       C    1
# 3   newark       J    1
# 4  seattle       A    2
# 5  seattle       D    2
```

Also, I heard a request for `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
join(data, data.frame(table(location = data$location)))
# Joining by: location
# location species Freq
# 1  seattle       A    2
# 2  buffalo       C    1
# 3  seattle       D    2
# 4   newark       J    1
# 5   boston       Q    1
```

Comment: nah, the "right" `plyr` solution I think is: `ddply(df, .(location), mutate, freq.loc = length(location))`

Comment: By "right" I meant "conceptually correct", at least as far as the `plyr` framework goes, and not faster. I can't say I care about the speed of either since I'm firmly in the "`data.table` does this way better" camp, but if that's of interest to you, then you should do it and post the results. Using a benchmarking package like `microbenchmark` would probably be best if you do it.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to work with dashes in column names will be very painful. Better to use underscores or "dots".

```
dfrm$freq_loc <- ave( as.numeric(dat[[1]]), dat[["location"]] ,
                                                     FUN=length)
```

I trying using `ave` without the `as.numeric` on the first column, but to my surprise got cryptic error messages related to factor levels.